# Why does chkconfig highlight the word "on" by default in Precise?

Tags: command-line, services

Why does chkconfig highlight the word "on" by default in Ubuntu Precise?

[image: screenshot of chkconfig in terminal with highlighting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's what it does. It's by design, I assume to help people notice.

From `man chkconfig`, emphasis mine:

> List mode prints for each specified service a line that consists of the service name and for runlevels zero to six on or off depending if the service will be started or not. **on will be printed  in  bright green if the output is written to a terminal.** If the --deps option is given, the names of the services that must be started before this service is appended to  each  line.  The  inetd/xinetd  services  are listed in extra sections.

Answer (score 2):

`chkconfig` doesn't just highlight the *word* `on`. It highlights the whole table entry, when the entry represents a symbolic link (to a script in `/etc/init.d`) through which the service is enabled.

As you may know, a common way to configure whether a system service starts up automatically or not, and *when during system startup* it starts, is with symbolic links stored in eight subdirectories of `/etc`: `rc0.d`, `rc1.d`, `rc2.d`, `rc3.d`, `rc4.d`, `rc5.d`, `rc6.d`, and `rcS.d`. Those directories contain symbolic links to scripts in `/etc/init.d` that start and stop services. The symbolic links' names usually start with `S` to start a service or `K` not to start it. `chkconfig` shows you information about this configuration, and lets you modify it.

Most of the time when a user runs `chkconfig --list`, the user wants to see **what services are enabled** and **where they are enabled** (i.e., through what symbolic link or links, in what `rcX.d` directories). Therefore, it makes sense for `chkconfig` to highlight the entries representing scripts that cause services to be run.

These are the entries that contain the word `on`. But there is nothing special about that word. It's the entries that contain it that are special, because they represent what a user is most often looking for when running `chkconfig --list`.

#### What if you want to run `chkconfig --list` without the highlighting?

It [doesn't appear](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/chkconfig.8.html) that there is any special command-line flag to turn color off. There might be an environment variable to do so. But i believe you can simply run:

```
chkconfig --list | cat
```

I cannot test this at the moment because I don't have an Ubuntu system on which I can currently install `chkconfig`. But most of the time, programs featuring colored output will automatically detect when standard output is not a terminal, and disable it (since it would often not work properly). By piping the output of `chkconfig --list` to `cat`, you prevent stdout from being a terminal, while still seeing the output on your terminal.

Comment: I tested on my Debian (which has the same configuration) and `| cat` disable the colouring